# Adding a remove circle button

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to create a website that allows me to click the markers on the map and a circle will appear highlighting the area. I have coded it to work but however, I am unable to remove the circle unlike the infowindow. I wish to have a remove circle button that might remove all the circles in the map(if multiple circles are display on the map) like the remove button in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-remove. If not, maybe make the circle disappear when click on another marker.

Also, how to I prevent the circle from getting more opaque when the user spam the marker?

This is my code:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891),
      zoom: 4,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
    setMarkers(map, atm);
}

var atm = [
           ['<h1 class="big">newyork</h1>',40.714352, -74.005973,2],
           ['<h1 class="big">losangeles</h1>',34.052234, -118.243684,1],
           ['<h1 class="big">vancouver</h1>',49.25, -123.1,3],
           ];

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({   
    maxWidth: 200
});

  function setMarkers(map, locations) {
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var atms = locations[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(atms[1], atms[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: atms[0],
            zIndex: atms[3]
        });


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
         infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
         infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
       })(marker, i));

       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
          return function() {                     
           var myCity = new google.maps.Circle({
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            radius:20000,
            strokeColor:"#0000FF",
            strokeOpacity:0.8,
            strokeWeight:2,
            fillColor:"#0000FF",
            fillOpacity:0.3
           });
           myCity.setMap(map)
           }
         })(marker, i));
       }
    }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Hopefully, a function like

```
function removeLine() {
 flightPath.setMap(null);
}
```

Which allows me to create

```
<input onclick="removeLine();" type=button value="Remove line">
```

Answer (score 0):

You would add the marker's circle as a property of itself using the `this` scope.

Then you can simply retrieve the marker and it's circle and remove it from the map.  Also this way it will only draw one circle per marker and prevent the addition of multiple circles per marker.

```
markerCircles = [];

function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    setMarkers(map, atm);
}

var atm = [
    ['<h1 class="big">newyork</h1>', 40.714352, -74.005973, 2],
    ['<h1 class="big">losangeles</h1>', 34.052234, -118.243684, 1],
    ['<h1 class="big">vancouver</h1>', 49.25, -123.1, 3], ];

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    maxWidth: 200
});

function setMarkers(map, locations) {
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var atms = locations[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(atms[1], atms[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            markerDataIndex: i,
            circle: false,
            title: atms[0],
            zIndex: atms[3]
        });


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (marker, i) {
            console.log(this.markerDataIndex);
            infowindow.setContent(atm[this.markerDataIndex][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
            if (!this.circle) {
                var myCity = new google.maps.Circle({
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(atm[this.markerDataIndex][1], atm[this.markerDataIndex][2]),
                    radius: 20000,
                    strokeColor: "#0000FF",
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    fillColor: "#0000FF",
                    fillOpacity: 0.3
                });
                myCity.setMap(map);
                markerCircles.push(this);
                this.circle = myCity;
            }
        });
    }
}

window.removeCircles = function () {
    markerCircles.forEach(function (marker, index, circleArray) {
        console.log(marker);
        marker.circle.setMap(null);
        marker.circle = false;
    });
    markerCircles = [];
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/1pry2gwj/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your circle is a local variable to your marker's click event handler.

I'd say make your markers array a global variable.  When you create a circle, set that as a property on the marker.

For each remove button, pass an ID which links the button with the marker who's circle you want to remove.  Something like:

```
function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
    setMarkers(map, atm);
}

var markers = [];
var atm = [
    ['<h1 class="big">newyork</h1>', 40.714352, -74.005973, 2],
    ['<h1 class="big">losangeles</h1>', 34.052234, -118.243684, 1],
    ['<h1 class="big">vancouver</h1>', 49.25, -123.1, 3],
];

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    maxWidth: 200
});

function setMarkers(map, locations) {
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var atms = locations[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(atms[1], atms[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: atms[0],
            zIndex: atms[3]
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);

                var myCity = new google.maps.Circle({
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                    radius: 20000,
                    strokeColor: "#0000FF",
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    fillColor: "#0000FF",
                    fillOpacity: 0.3,
                    map: map
                });

                marker.set("circle", myCity);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        markers.push(marker);
    }
}


function removeLine(marker) {
    markers[marker].circle.setMap(null);
}
```

and then (in reality you'd probably use JS to loop over your `atm` array to output these):

```
<input onclick="removeLine(0);" type=button value="Remove line 1">
<input onclick="removeLine(1);" type=button value="Remove line 2">
<input onclick="removeLine(2);" type=button value="Remove line 3">
```